# Create a role with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
  interviewee_role = await guild.create_role(
        name=member.id,
        read_messages=True,
        read_message_history=True,
        send_messages=True,
        send_tts_messages=True,
        attach_files=True,
        manage_messages=False,
    )
```

what I'm trying to do is

create a role that server doesn't have it yet then give it to a member
but don't know how to give permissions

stated all permissions that I want to give then get errors

Comment: Your title and question is unclear. Would you mind adding more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Guild.create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role) doesn't accept specific permissions as parameters but rather a [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) object as the `permissions` parameter. You'll need to initialize a `Permissions` object with the raw value, use [`Permissions.update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.update), or update each permission attribute manually beore passing it to `Guild.create_role`. If you are using the latest development version of discord.py, you can just initialize it with keyword arguments.

In the future, please provide a full traceback when asking for help with your code.
Just the fact that you're getting errors isn't helpful and doesn't provide any information about the actual issue.